# VB.NET - Provide predefined creation settings in a class

Tags: vb.net, class, constructor

I'm writing a theming class called `FormTheme` for a VB.NET form application. It contains colour scheme information that can be applied at runtime to form controls. Currently there are three ways to instantiate an object:

```
Public Sub New()
```

Creates a new theme with the default system colours.

```
Public Sub New(ByVal ForeColor As Color, _
                      ByVal BackColor As Color, _
              ByVal BorderColor As Color ... )
```

Creates a new theme with the provided colours.

```
Public Sub New(ByRef ExistingTheme As FormTheme)
```

Creates a new theme by doing a 'deep copy' of an existing theme.

I would like to provide a fourth option to create a theme based on pre-defined settings, for example:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal scheme As ColorScheme)
'usage: Dim myTheme As New FormTheme(ColorScheme.Night)
```

Was wondering what would be the best way to implement this? Considered using an `Enum` and a `Select Case` statement in the constructor to theme based on the enum value, which would certainly work:

```
Enum ColorScheme
  Day
  Night
  City
  Candy
  ...
End Enum

Public Sub New(ByVal scheme as ColorScheme)
  Select scheme
    Case ColorScheme.Day
      'Set colors
    Case ColorScheme.Night
      'Set colors
    Case ColorScheme.City
      'Set colors
    ...
  End Select
End Sub
```

Before I forge ahead, is there a more standard or 'better' way of doing this?

Comment: It seems a perfectly valid approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a good ways of doing it.

You could always preload all the colorsccheme in a dictionnary

```
Dim colorSchemeList As Dictionnary(Of ColorScheme, FormTheme)
```

Loaded in a static constructor and them your New would look something like

```
Public Sub New(ByVal scheme as ColorScheme)
    New(colorSchemeList(scheme))
End Sub
```

Comment: Aha, the dictionary seems a good idea, since it was the sheer potential length of the ctor that made me pause.